# infinite fetch request with react-promise-tracker

Tags: javascript, reactjs, promise, fetch

I am fetching data from an external API using the fetch API. I would like to implement a loading cursor while the request is fetching the data. For this I'm trying to use the react-promise-tracker library. But when using the trackPromise from the library, the fetching repeats itself infinitely.

You can see the bug happening yourself when changing the commented code in this example project (check the console this is all happening in console.log):
https://codesandbox.io/s/tender-easley-szfxg?file=/src/App.tsx

Basically this works:

```
export default function App() {
  const get = (url: string) => {
    let headers: {
      Accept: string;
      "Content-Type": string;
    } = {
      Accept: "application/ld+json",
      "Content-Type": "application/json"
    };
   
    return fetch(url, {
      method: "GET",
      headers
    } as RequestInit)
      .then((res: Response) => {
        if (res.ok) {
          return res.json();
        }

        return Promise.reject(res);
      })
      .catch(Promise.reject.bind(Promise));
  };
  get("https://608bb5b6737e470017b752e2.mockapi.io/users")
    .then(console.log)
    .catch(console.log);

  return <div>nothing</div>;
}
```

this doesn't:

```
import { usePromiseTracker, trackPromise } from "react-promise-tracker";   // ADDED CODE

export default function App() {
  const { promiseInProgress } = usePromiseTracker({ area: "fetchDataGet" });      // ADDED CODE
  const cursorStyle = () => {                                                     // ADDED CODE
    return promiseInProgress ? { cursor: "wait" } : undefined;                    // ADDED CODE
  };                                                                              // ADDED CODE
  const get = (url: string) => {
    let headers: {
      Accept: string;
      "Content-Type": string;
    } = {
      Accept: "application/ld+json",
      "Content-Type": "application/json"
    };
    return trackPromise(                                                           // ADDED CODE
      fetch(url, {
        method: "GET",
        headers
      } as RequestInit)
        .then((res: Response) => {
          if (res.ok) {
            return res.json();
          }

          return Promise.reject(res);
        })
        .catch(Promise.reject.bind(Promise)),
      "fetchDataGet"                                                               // ADDED CODE
    );
  };
  get("https://608bb5b6737e470017b752e2.mockapi.io/users")
    .then(console.log)
    .catch(console.log);

  return <div style={cursorStyle()}>nothing</div>;
}
```

The ouput of the second code is several console.log when it should be only 1 and at some point the servers returns a 429 error (which is normal, it's just server security)

Comment: You are unconditionally calling `get(...)` during render. Every time your component re-renders you will trigger a new request and it re-renders whenever the promise resolves/gets rejected. You likely want to wrap it in a `useEffect`.

Comment: If you want to save yourself a lot of headaches you should take a look at [react-query](https://react-query.tanstack.com/) which provides hooks specifically aimed to fetch data.

Comment: @trixn fair point, but this is only the case in this example, in my actual code I'm using a useEffect. In this example the component doesn't rerender because the fetching only triggers a console.log

Comment: In your second example you are not using `useEffect` and instead call `get()` inside of the component body (which means it will be called every time the component renders). `usePromiseTracker` will trigger a state change and therefore a re-render every time your request promise resolves. This will definitely lead to an infinite loop of fetching which is exactly what you were asking about to solve. What did I miss here?

Comment: Generally speaking you should never ever unconditionally trigger any side-effects (like fetching data) inside of the component body. It should always be inside of either an effect that only runs at certain points in time or inside of an event handler.

Comment: OK it does solve my example. I don't understand why my actual code is relaunching the request infinitely though... I'll have a closer look at all the function calls if I missed one that is not in a useEffect. Thanks for the help though, this counts as an answer to me ;)

Comment: If you share your actual code I might be able to help you spot the problem. Effects can also run on every render if you define the dependencies wrong.

Comment: But I stronly suggest you take a look at react-query. react-promise-tracker is a very low level helper and doesn't solve a lot of problems that arise when dealing with data fetching. I also don't like it because it uses global identifiers across your whole app which makes it very easy to introduce subtile bugs that are hard to find.

Comment: The actual code is a whole complex project with a lot of fetches using the get function I defined above. I want to track all these fetches, that's why I implemented the promise-tracker inside this get function. I'll check all the effects and their dependencies too. I'll also have a look at react-query, thanks. If you want to write a quick answer I can accept it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your second example you are not using `useEffect` and instead call `get()` inside of the component body (which means it will be called every time the component renders). `usePromiseTracker` will trigger a state change and therefore a re-render every time your request promise resolves. This will definitely lead to an infinite loop of fetching.

Generally speaking you should never ever unconditionally trigger any side-effects (like fetching data) inside of the component body. It should always be inside of either an effect that only runs at certain points in time or inside of an event handler.

In this specific case you could solve it by warping you `get()` call in an effect:

```
useEffect(() => {
    get("https://608bb5b6737e470017b752e2.mockapi.io/users")
    .then(console.log)
    .catch(console.log);
}, []); // will only be called once after mounting
```

If you have this kind of code frequently in your project you should extract a custom hook that does this internally and also hides `usePromiseTracker` so you don't have to explicitly use it every time you want to fetch something:

```
const useFetch = (area, url, options) => {
    const { promiseInProgress } = usePromiseTracker({area});

    useEffect(() => {
        trackPromise(                                                           
            fetch(url, options)
                .then(res => res.ok ? res.json() : Promise.reject(res))
                .catch(Promise.reject.bind(Promise)),
            area,                                                               
        );
    }, []);

    return promiseInProgress;
};
```